# Ionic 3 - Typescript error: An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a click action when a user click on a like button for increment the number but when build or run the ionic app, i have a typescript error, can someone help me out with the solution?

```
Typescript Error
An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
src/pages/comments/comments.ts
document.getElementById("like-" + commentid).innerHTML++
```

In comments.ts

```
likedislike(type,commentid) {
  if(type === 'like') {
    document.getElementById("like-" + commentid).innerHTML++
  }
}
```

Comment: you would be using angular here.. the correct approach would be to use data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Number()`to cast the inner html string to number.

```
var x = document.getElementById("like-" + commentid).innerHTML; 

document.getElementById("like-" + commentid).innerHTML = Number(x) + 1
```

It is way beter to do this with Angular data binding in Ionic though...

Comment: Not working but finally i have create a voting component, work perfect now. Thanks for your help.